# Join two almost identical sql result rows with no null values

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, join, left-join

I am trying to get the currentManager and beforeManager from this sql query, but I am doing something wrong with IF statements I guess..
There is a sql query:

```
SELECT number, year_made, model,
IF(car_management.date_to >= NOW(), users.name, null) AS currentManager,
IF(car_management.date_to < NOW(), users.name, null) AS beforeManager,
statuses.name AS statusName
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN car_management ON car_management.cars_id = cars.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = car_management.user_id
LEFT JOIN car_status ON car_status.cars_id = cars.id
LEFT JOIN statuses ON statuses.id = car_status.status_id
```

And I am getting result with the NULL's where IF statement returns else, result below:

[Sql query result photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpgX.png)

I need these 4 lines to be joined in two instead NULL's with joined values.

Someone have any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

for reduce the rows  you could try using a (fake) aggregation function max() and group by

```
    SELECT number, year_made, model,
    max(IF(car_management.date_to >= NOW(), users.name, null)) AS currentManager,
    max(IF(car_management.date_to < NOW(), users.name, null)) AS beforeManager,
    statuses.name AS statusName
    FROM cars
    LEFT JOIN car_management ON car_management.cars_id = cars.id
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = car_management.user_id
    LEFT JOIN car_status ON car_status.cars_id = cars.id
    LEFT JOIN statuses ON statuses.id = car_status.status_id
    GROUP BY number, year_made, model, statuses.name
```